Connect Rotary Encoder (5V) to Raspberry PI
I am trying to connect my Rotary Encoder to my Raspberry Pi.
My Rotary Encoder has 4 Cables:A++,B++,VCC and 0V.
Here is my Logical Converter:!Logical Converter](https://europe1.discourse-cdn.com/arduino/original/4X/1/9/d/19d41d61fc59ad3def8ddd8027d5d6c26f4cc2af.jpeg)
How do i connect the Rotary Encoder, Logical Inverter and Raspberry PI?
My 3.3V Encoder is running smoothly but im struggling to connect my 5V Encoder to the Raspberry.
Regards

which rotary encoder are you using?

Rotary Encoder

please add the info to the question... a comment is not the place for it

what is the actual output voltage of the encoder?  ... add the info to the question, do not write a comment
